# strange behavior in C function, string is not carried over

Tags: c, string, casting

I have a function as such:

```
int foo(void *val){
(char *)val="Long String";
return 0;
}
```

This function is called like:

```
char str[25];
foo(str);
printf("%s",str);
```

I get nothing printed out for some reason. what is wrong here?

Comment: on a different note: using a void pointer here isn't good practice. You can't be sure, that there is enough space reserved for a char-array (string). I'd suggest checking that.

Comment: @robustus my function actually is more than just foo(*void), there's a few other params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You store the pointer to `"Long String"` into a variable `val` which is allocated **on the stack**. The lifetime of the variable extends only during the call to `foo()`.

You don't want to store the address to `"Long String"` on the stack. You want to **copy** the string under the provided address.

You should do this instead:

```
int foo(void *val){
  strcpy((char*)val, "Long String");
  return 0;
}
```

This isn't safe, though. You should pass the maximum size of the buffer into `foo` and use `strncpy()` instead of `strcpy()`.

Comment: just what I needed, everyone else was iterating the same thing but they changed the structure of my function, which in my case I'm not allowed to modify

Answer (score 3):

You are not actually copying the data around like you think you are.  All you are doing is changing the parameter value to point at a different memory address.  The parameter is being passed by value, so any change to it is not reflected in the calling code.  For what you are attempting, you need to use `strcpy()` or `strncpy()` instead, eg:

```
int foo(char *val)
{ 
    strcpy(val, "Long String");
    return 0; 
}
```

Or:

```
int foo(char *val, int maxlen)
{ 
    strncpy(val, "Long String", maxlen);
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not copying anything into `str`. You're just editing the pointer value that you passed in…

Calling `foo(str)` creates a new, temporary variable named `void* val`, and points it at `char[0]`. You then change `val` to point to the start of the string "Long String" instead.

If you actually want to fill the `char str[25]` buffer, use strncpy:

```
 int foo (char* buf)
   { return strncpy (buf, "Long String", 25); }
```

However, if you *ever* send this routine a `char[]` with less than 25 positions in it, you *will* have major problems.

I'd like to also suggest, against some suggestions that just appeared, that **`strcpy` should never be considered** for use in new code, and *definitely* not advocated to someone who's learning how to work with pointers and character arrays. That way lies pain.